# Ayudenme a escoger el metodo apropiado select o distinct

Tags: php, html, laravel

[image: Aqui podemos ver que me aparecen 2 extrusoras, lo cual solo debe mostarme una ya que cada maquinaria cuenta con una extrusora,]

Este es el metodo que estoy aplicando en el modelo, me gustaria que solo me motrara una extrusora ya que solo hay una extrusora en la linea 1

```
public function scopeAllEquipmentChild($query)
{
    return EquipmentChild::with('machinery', 'equipment')->
        leftjoin('equipment','equipment_children.equipment_id','=','equipment.id')
            ->join('machineries','equipment.machinery_id','=','machineries.id')
                ->select('equipment_children.*','equipment_children.name','equipment.machinery_id','machineries.area_id')
                    ->get();
}
```

Este es mi controller de las funciones create

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $machineries=machinery::pluck('name','id')->all();
    $areas=area::pluck('name','id')->all();
    return view('admin.equipment.create',compact('areas','machineries'));
}

/**
 * @param \App\Http\Requests\EquipmentStoreRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(EquipmentStoreRequest $request)
{
    $equipment = Equipment::create($request->validated());

    $request->session()->flash('equipment.id', $equipment->id);

    return redirect()->route('admin.equipment.index');
}
```

Comment: Si la tabla equipment tiene una lista de equipment's únicos, te sobran los joins. Si no es así, te falta un group by

Comment: Asi esta compuesto area->machinaries->equipment->equipment_child
Al moemnto de registrar un equipment-child escogo una maquinara y un equipo, hay partes que se repiten de las maquinarias pero no en un mismo equipo, y me esta apareciendo todos los equipos registrados y yo solo quiero que muestre los equipos registrados en cada linea, probe tus metodos y salio error en los dos @Yussef